# NSCoding leak problem with initWithCoder

Tags: objective-c, ipad, memory-leaks, nscoding

I have a leak in the following code:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.Tag = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:KEY_TAG];
        self.ParentTag = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:KEY_PARENT_TAG];
        self.Order = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:KEY_ORDER];
        self.OrderFavorite = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:KEY_ORDER_FAVORITE];
        self.isFavorite = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:KEY_IS_FAVORITE];
        self.isPurchased = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:KEY_IS_PURCHASED];

        self.Titel = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:KEY_TITEL];
    }
    return self;
}
```

The leak appears in instruments on the device in that line:

```
self.Titel = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:KEY_TITEL];
```

KEY_TITEL is:

```
#define KEY_TITEL @"Titel"
```

and self.Titel is:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *Titel;
```

it is synthesize and it is released in dealloc.

I don't have any idea where the leak is come from.
Can you help me out please...

thank you
xnz

Answer (score 3):

You're mis-interpreting what Instruments is telling you.

It is **not** telling you where you leaked an object.

It *is* telling you where you created an object that was eventually leaked.

Reanalyze the data from Instruments accordingly.  (You're likely missing a `[Titel release]` call in your `-dealloc` method)

Answer (score 0):

Do have you assign a value to `Titel` before `initWithCoder` execution ? Maybe in super class ?
The leak does not seem to be linked to the `initWithCoder` execution, but to a previous assignment.

Comment: If I don't find the archived object, I assign it from a Dictionary. But if I do so then initWithCoder is not called. Superclass is NSObject, so I don't assign it there.